# Can an A&P who is also a private pilot receive compensation for conducting maintenance test flights?

Tags: faa-regulations, aircraft-maintenance

*[Related to this question.](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/22936/167)*

Suppose a repair is made to an airplane and a maintenance test flight is required. Suppose the A&P who works on the aircraft is also a private pilot. That person performs the test flight and then signs off the repair.  (assume USA)

A private pilot can't fly for compensation or hire.

Can the mechanic bill for the time she spent flying?  Are maintenance test flights considered incidental to a mechanic's business?

Comment: Even better, does the mechanic have to pay for the fuel burned during the flight?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the mechanic can fly the aircraft, according to [this FAA legal interpretation](https://web.archive.org/web/20170228152246/http://www.faa.gov:80/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/agc/pol_adjudication/agc200/interpretations/data/interps/2014/williams-larrywilliamsassoc%20-%20(2014)%20legal%20interpretation.pdf) (Williams, 2014):

> The scenario you present is a mechanic who, as part of his duties,
>   conducts flight tests after performing maintenance on the aircraft,
>   and does not carry passengers or property for compensation or hire.
>   The mechanic holds a private pilot certificate with a valid third
>   class medical certificate. This situation is covered under §
>   61.113(b), which states that, "[a] private pilot may, for compensation or hire, act as pilot in command of an aircraft in connection with any
>   business or employment if (1) the flight is only incidental to that
>   business or employment and (2) the aircraft does not carry passengers
>   or property for compensation or hire." As these flight tests are
>   incidental to his employment as a mechanic, the mechanic is not in
>   violation of § 61.113 when conducting these flight tests

Comment: Well how about that.